# Third Hole in Cribbage Board

Tags: cribbage

What is the third hole at the start of the cribbage for?

It's shown behind the 2 pegs in the image below:

[image: Cribbage board]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That is for the Game Peg (also known as a spilikin). At the bottom of the board, you see the three straight stripes - those are for keeping track of the number of games you have won. Until you have actually won a game, your spilikin for tracking wins is stored in that third hole.

Consider the following picture: it appears blue has just won the game, and is awarded two game wins for skunking the red player. The red player has yet to win a game, so his spilikin is still in the starting position.

[image]

Comment: The wacky terminology is half the fun of playing cribbage.